# How to create a factory without initializing objects that are not used

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have two classes that implement the same interface and I want to inject one of them accordingly to a feature toggle (boolean).

```java
public class A implements MyInterface { 
   public A(C obj1, D obj2);
   ... 
}

public class B implements MyInterface { 
   public A(E obj1, F obj2);
   ... 
}

public class Target { 
   Target(MyInterface obj1);
   ... 
}
```

```xml
<bean id="myAclass"
    class="com.project.A"
    c:obj1-ref="project-C"
    c:obj2-ref="project-D"
/>

<bean id="myBclass"
    class="com.project.B"
    c:obj1-ref="project-E"
    c:obj2-ref="project-F"
/>

<bean id="targetClass"
    class="com.project.Target"
    c:obj-ref="????"
/>
```

This is the typical use case for a factory method:

```
public class Factory {
 
 public Factory(A a, B b){
  ...
 } 

 private static MyInterface build(boolean toggleValue) {
    return toggleValue ? this.a : this.b;           
 }

}
```

However, In runtime I want to initialize only one of this objects, including their dependencies (C/D or E/F classes). What is the graceful way of doing that?

Comment: What about [spring-profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) have you tried ?

Comment: The code of the factory makes no sense. You can not access `this` in a `static` method. Further, it’s not a factory by any standard. A factory is, as the name suggests, supposed to *create* the result inside the `build` method, not to return an already existing object. In your code, it’s even worse as the prebuilt objects are not even created in the factory, but somewhere else and passed to the factory’s constructor. So what you called `Factory` is just a container but even as container, it’s useless as the accessor method is `private`.